# How to compare two Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, collections

I have two generic Dictionaries. Both have the same keys, but their values can be different. I want to compare the 2nd dictionary with the 1st dictionary. If there are differences between their values, I want to store those values in a separate dictionary.

```
1st Dictionary
------------
key       Value

Barcode   1234566666
Price     20.00


2nd Dictionary
--------------
key       Value

Barcode   1234566666
Price     40.00


3rd Dictionary
--------------
key       Value

Price     40
```

Can anyone give me the best algorithm to do this? I wrote an algorithm but it has a lot of loops. I am seeking a short and efficient idea, like a solution using LINQ query expressions or LINQ lambda expressions. I am using .NET Framework 3.5 with C#. I found something about the `Except()` method, but unfortunately I couldn't understand what is happening on that method. It would be great if anyone could explain the suggested algorithm.

Comment: What do you want to do if a key appears in the first dictionary but not the second, or vice versa?

Comment: No...actually keys must be same in name and count.I am checking by iscontains() method before go to algorithm.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you've already checked that the keys are the same, you can just use:

```
var dict3 = dict2.Where(entry => dict1[entry.Key] != entry.Value)
                 .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

To explain, this will:

- Iterate over the key/value pairs in `dict2`
- For each entry, look up the value in `dict1` and filter out any entries where the two values are the same
- Form a dictionary from the remaining entries (i.e. the ones where the `dict1` value is different) by taking the key and value from each pair just as they appear in `dict2`.

Note that this avoids relying on the equality of [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) - it *might* be okay to rely on that, but personally I find this clearer. (It will also work when you're using a custom equality comparer for the dictionary keys - although you'd need to pass that to `ToDictionary`, too.)

Answer (score 53):

try :

```
dictionary1.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
           .SequenceEqual(dictionary2.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key))
```

Comment: Is this compare with values? is this return a collection or boolean.

Comment: I tried several different options with the Dictionary key being a string and this one seemed to be the fastest by far.

Comment: @Thabo Yes. `SequenceEqual` uses the default equality comparer for `KeyValuePair` which examines both the key and the value.

Answer (score 43):

to check any difference,

```
dic1.Count == dic2.Count && !dic1.Except(dic2).Any();
```

following code return all the different values

```
dic1.Except(dic2)
```

Comment: can you explain this little bit?:)

Comment: @Thabo: The dictionaries are equivalent if they are the same size and there are no elements which are in the first and not in the second. second line directly return all the elements which are in the first and not in the second

Comment: Where is ".Except( )" coming from?  I tried this with an OrderedDictionary and got: 
Error CS1061 'OrderedDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and no accessible extension method 'Except' accepting a first argument of type 'OrderedDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @RichardB Linq. Add `using System.Linq;` at top of file, and try again.

Answer (score 14):

You mentioned that both dictionaries have the same keys, so if this assumption is correct, you don't need anything fancy:

```
        foreach (var key in d1.Keys)
        {
            if (!d1[key].Equals(d2[key]))
            {
                d3.Add(key, d2[key]);
            }
        }
```

Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: You should do `!d1[key].Equals(d2[key])`

Comment: ooops...it is simple..i dint think like this but one doubt is this good in performance. because i always like to avoid Order n operations.

Comment: You're missing a `!`, since you want the different values, not the equal ones.

Comment: @Thabo Yes, this is approaching an O(n) operation. Since it has to compare all values at least once, O(n) is pretty much as low as you can go.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming both dictionaries have the same keys, the simplest way is

```
var result = a.Except(b).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

**EDIT**

Note that `a.Except(b)` gives a different result from `b.Except(a)`:

```
a.Except(b): Price     20
b.Except(a): Price     40
```

Comment: what if the order of keys is different in both dictionaries?is this work?

Comment: @Thabo Yes. But note that `a.Except(b)` gives a different result from `b.Except(a)`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to join them on their keys and select both values. Then you can filter based on whether the values are the same or different. Finally, you can convert the collection to a dictionary with the keys and second values.

```
  var compared = first.Join( second, f => f.Key, s => s.Key, (f,s) => new { f.Key, FirstValue = f.Value, SecondValue = s.Value } )
                      .Where( j => j.FirstValue != j.SecondValue )
                      .ToDictionary( j => j.Key, j => j.SecondValue );
```

Using a loop shouldn't be too bad either.  I suspect that they would have similar performance characteristics.

```
  var compared = new Dictionary<string,object>();
  foreach (var kv in first)
  {
      object secondValue;
      if (second.TryGetValue( kv.Key, out secondValue ))
      {
            if (!object.Equals( kv.Value, secondValue ))
            {
                compared.Add( kv.Key, secondValue );
            }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var diff1 = d1.Except(d2);
var diff2 = d2.Except(d1);
return diff1.Concat(diff2);
```

**Edit:** If you sure all keys are same you can do:

```
var diff = d2.Where(x=>x.Value != d1[x.Key]).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: This doesn't result in a dictionary though, but with an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`

Comment: For first on we can't have dictionary, but for second one I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In recent C# versions you can try

```cs
        public static Dictionary<TK, TV> ValueDiff<TK, TV>(this Dictionary<TK, TV> dictionary,
            Dictionary<TK, TV> otherDictionary)
        {
            IEnumerable<(TK key, TV otherValue)> DiffKey(KeyValuePair<TK, TV> kv)
            {
                var otherValue = otherDictionary[kv.Key];
                if (!Equals(kv.Value, otherValue))
                {
                    yield return (kv.Key, otherValue);
                }
            }

            return dictionary.SelectMany(DiffKey)
                .ToDictionary(t => t.key, t => t.otherValue, dictionary.Comparer);
        }
```

I am not sure that `SelectMany`is always the fastest solution, but it is one way to only select the relevant items and generate the resulting entries in the same step. Sadly C# does not support `yield return` in lambdas and while I could have constructed single or no item collections, I choose to use an inner function.

Oh and as you say that the keys are the same, it may be possible to order them. Then you could use `Zip`

```cs
        public static Dictionary<TK, TV> ValueDiff<TK, TV>(this Dictionary<TK, TV> dictionary,
            Dictionary<TK, TV> otherDictionary)
        {
            return dictionary.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key)
                .Zip(otherDictionary.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key))
                .Where(p => !Equals(p.First.Value, p.Second.Value))
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Second.Key, p => p.Second.Value, dictionary.Comparer);
        }
```

Personally I would tend not to use Linq, but a simple `foreach` like carlosfigueira and vanfosson:

```cs
        public static Dictionary<TK, TV> ValueDiff2<TK, TV>(this Dictionary<TK, TV> dictionary,
            Dictionary<TK, TV> otherDictionary)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<TK, TV>(dictionary.Count, dictionary.Comparer);
            foreach (var (key, value) in dictionary)
            {
                var otherValue = otherDictionary[key];
                if (!Equals(value, otherValue))
                {
                    result.Add(key, otherValue);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: From the question: *If there are differences between values i want to store those values in separate dictionary*

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I must have been tired; I rewrote my answer. I came here googling and seem not to have read the question at all. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

if you need a full comparison of both (think venn diagram results), there are four discrete outcomes for a given key assuming it is present in at least one of the dictionaries

```cs
public enum KeyCompareResult
{
  ValueEqual,
  NotInLeft,
  NotInRight,
  ValueNotEqual,
}
```

To get all of the keys in a dictionary, use `dictionary.Keys`. To get the set of keys in either dictionary, use `Enumerable.Union`, which will combine the sets and filter out duplicates.

Assuming you want some more generic method, you can then write your comparison as

```cs
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, KeyCompareResult>> GetDifferences<TKey, TValue>(
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> leftDict,
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> rightDict,
    IEqualityComparer<TValue> comparer = null)
{
    var keys = leftDict.Keys.Union(rightDict.Keys);
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    return keys.Select(key =>
    {
        if (!leftDict.TryGetValue(key, out var left))
        {
            return KeyValuePair.Create<TKey, KeyCompareResult>(key, KeyCompareResult.NotInLeft);
        }
        else if (!rightDict.TryGetValue(key, out var right))
        {
            return KeyValuePair.Create<TKey, KeyCompareResult>(key, KeyCompareResult.NotInRight);
        }
        else if (!comparer.Equals(left, right))
        {
            return KeyValuePair.Create<TKey, KeyCompareResult>(key, KeyCompareResult.ValueNotEqual);
        }
        else
        {
            return KeyValuePair.Create<TKey, KeyCompareResult>(key, KeyCompareResult.ValueEqual);
        }
    });
}
```

The left/right distinction isn't obvious unless you are looking at the method call, so, you probably want to select the method results into messages or some other more meaningful data structure

```cs
var left = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 4, "four" } };
var right = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "A different value" }, { 3, "three" } };

GetDifferences(left, right, StringComparer.InvariantCulture)
    .Display(); // or however you want to process the data
/*
Key Value
--- -------------
  1 ValueEqual 
  2 ValueNotEqual 
  4 NotInRight 
  3 NotInLeft 
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would compare two dictionaries in this way:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"1","1" },
    {"2","1" },
    {"3","3" },
};

Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"1","1" },
    {"3","3" },
    {"2","1" },
};

var areEqaul = dict1.Count == dict2.Count && !dict1.Keys.Any(key => !dict2.Keys.Contains(key)) &&
    !dict1.Keys.Any(key => dict2[key] != dict1[key]));
```

Basically, I check if the keys are whether same or not if keys were the same then check the corresponding values per key in both dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

> converting the object to dictionary then following set concept subtract them, result items should be empty in case they are identically.

```
 public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object source)
    {
        var fields = source.GetType().GetFields(
            BindingFlags.GetField |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Instance).ToDictionary
        (
            propInfo => propInfo.Name,
            propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(source) ?? string.Empty
        );

        var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.GetField |
            BindingFlags.GetProperty |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Instance).ToDictionary
        (
            propInfo => propInfo.Name,
            propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(source, null) ?? string.Empty
        );

        return fields.Concat(properties).ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Value); ;
    }
    public static bool EqualsByValue(this object source, object destination)
    {
        var firstDic = source.ToFlattenDictionary();
        var secondDic = destination.ToFlattenDictionary();
        if (firstDic.Count != secondDic.Count)
            return false;
        if (firstDic.Keys.Except(secondDic.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        if (secondDic.Keys.Except(firstDic.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        return firstDic.All(pair =>
          pair.Value.ToString().Equals(secondDic[pair.Key].ToString())
        );
    }
    public static bool IsAnonymousType(this object instance)
    {

        if (instance == null)
            return false;

        return instance.GetType().Namespace == null;
    }
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToFlattenDictionary(this object source, string parentPropertyKey = null, IDictionary<string, object> parentPropertyValue = null)
    {
        var propsDic = parentPropertyValue ?? new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var item in source.ToDictionary())
        {
            var key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentPropertyKey) ? item.Key : $"{parentPropertyKey}.{item.Key}";
            if (item.Value.IsAnonymousType())
                return item.Value.ToFlattenDictionary(key, propsDic);
            else
                propsDic.Add(key, item.Value);
        }
        return propsDic;
    }
originalObj.EqualsByValue(messageBody); // will compare values.
```

[source of the code](https://github.com/mohamed-abdo/string-template-parser/blob/master/TemplateParser/HelperExt.cs)

Answer (score 0):

A simple LINQ function that compares the keys and values

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

bool DictionariesAreEqual(Dictionary<object, object> d1, Dictionary<object, object> d2)
{
    // If any keys are missing/extra/different, the dicts are not the same
    if (!d1.Keys.ToHashSet().SetEquals(d2.Keys.ToHashSet()))
        return false;

    // Next we count the differences between the corresponding values d1[key] and d2[key]
     return d1.Where((kvp) => kvp.Value != d2[kvp.Key]).Count() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension method to compare two dictionaries

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEquivalent<k, v>(this IDictionary<k, v> a, IDictionary<k, v> b)
    {
        return a.Keys.ToHashSet().SetEquals(b.Keys.ToHashSet()) &&
               a.All(p => Equals(p.Value, b[p.Key]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Serialize the Dictionaries to a string:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new OrderedContractResolver() };
var sourceHash = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary1, jsonSerializerSettings).GetHashCode();
var blobHash = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary2, jsonSerializerSettings).GetHashCode();

public class OrderedContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        return base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).OrderBy(p => p.PropertyName).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then compare the HashCodes (or just the json strings). This code forces the parameters to appear in consistent order, so if your dictionaries contain the same values out of order, they should return equal.

This solution avoids the edge case of comparing a dictionary which is a subset to a larger dictionary, which will return equal in many of the other answers. This solution will likely be inefficient for very large dictionaries or if you are making a large number of comparisons - but it is simple.

Comment: This way you are comparing two strings. That's not what the OP is asking for.