# Fastest way to check a Dictionary<> is equal to another

Tags: c#

Has anyone tried this, have any thoughts on what's the best approach?

I have a `Dictionary<SimpleClassContainingOneStringProperty, decimal>` and want to compare it against a previous snapshot of the same Dictionary<> object, to check if there has been a change to any of the data within the collection.

1) I can iterate through, running Equals() against each item.

2) I was thinking of using an MD5 checksum on the object.

3) Or, perhaps a way to convert the collection to it's byte representation as a `byte[]` and then running a simpler, faster equality check against two byte arrays?

Any feedback on these or any other ideas?

Comment: I would probably flip this on its head. Write a `Dictionary<>` wrapper that flags when a change is made.

Comment: It sounds like you should consider a Merkle or Patricia Trie structure.

Comment: This one too: [How to compare two Dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547351/how-to-compare-two-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should post sample code of what you're trying to accomplish but a Dictionary is inherently one of the fastest collection types in .NET.  Arrays are slower than dictionaries; so that plus the conversion would be twice the downgrade.